# Replace auto parameter with actual type in lambda using a variant type parameter

Tags: c++

I have a lambda that looks like this:

```cpp
click->subscribe([](auto a) { });
```

The type of `a` is this when the application is run:

```cpp
std::variant<
  std::monostate, 
  SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>, 
  SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*> *, 
  std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>
> [index 3] 
containing std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>> (use count 3, weak count 0)
```

As it points out (at run time) the value is of index `3` which is `std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>`. So, if I change `auto` to that type so it looks like this:

```cpp
click->subscribe([](std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>> a) { });
```

When I build the application, I get the following error:

```cpp
cannot convert 'FileBarLabel::FileBarLabel(std::string, Gtk::Notebook*)::<lambda(std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>)>' 
to 'ObserverOrNext<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>' 
{aka 
'std::variant<
  std::monostate, 
  std::function<void()>, 
  std::function<void(std::variant<
    std::monostate, 
    SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>, 
    SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>*, 
    std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>
  >)>,
  Subscriber<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>> 
>
'}
```

Is there a way for me to define the parameter to something other auto so I do not get the error?

Comment: `subscribe` seems to expect that you give it a function that is able to accept either a `SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>` or a `SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>*` or a `std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>` or an empty `variant`. But your lambda without `auto` will accept only one of those. So it doesn't fulfil the requirements of `subscribe`.

Comment: "_The type of a is this when the application is run:_": That happens to be the type in your particular execution, but the type of `subscribe`'s parameter expects that it can be _any_ of those at runtime. You can't statically assume only one of them.

Comment: Why not just stick with `auto`?

Comment: *Is there a way for me to define the parameter to something other auto as so I do not get the error?*  **Yes**, you can define it as that big `std::variant` type.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. So it sounds like I cannot, and the way to do what I want is to do something like this: `click->subscribe([](auto a) {
      auto evt = get<std::shared_ptr<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>>(a); });`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You still need to decide how to handle the case that you get a variant set to a different index. Your suggestion would throw an exception in that case. Nothing seems to indicate that you have any guarantee not to get a different index. The intent seems to be that you handle all possibly owning pointer types at the same time, e.g. with `std::visit`.

Comment: Did you try `ObserverOrNext<SignalEvent<Gtk::Button*>>` instead of `auto a`?